# Laravel/SQL get all parents

Tags: php, laravel

I have some slight problems with MySQL.
I have a categories table, where I have parent_id and it's associated with the same table (foreign id). So I'm trying to get all parents (not child), that are associated with all the other.

For example, I have 3 rows in the table

```
id     title     parent_id
1      test      null
2      test1     1
3      test2     2
```

So, when I want to get all parents for id = 3, I would need an response like (including the main one at the end):

```
[
 {
   id: 1
   title: test
 },
{
   id: 2
   title: test1
 },
{
   id: 3
   title: test2
 }
]
```

I tried like:

```
$parent = Category::where('forum_categories.id', $this->main->id)
                ->when(true, function ($query){
                    $query->join('forum_categories as parent', 'forum_categories.parent_id', '=', 'parent.id');
                    
                    $query->when(true, function($query){
                        $query->join('forum_categories as sub_parent', 'parent.parent_id', '=', 'sub_parent.id');

                    });
                })
                ->first();
```

but it's only getting a first parent and others are not shown.
And I have laravel relation for parent and looping a parents, and it works. But I need to get only certain parameters like title and it's not working. Any ideas how to select here or to continue with join?

```
$parent = Category::where('id', $this->main->id)
                ->with(['loopParents' => function ($query) {
                }])
                ->first();
```

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list) package.

Comment: How does `test` has id 1?